# How to remember wifi configuration and connected network through-out the reboots

Tags: android, android-wifi

I am using following code to create new wifi access point and to connect to it.
This code is working fine and i am able to connect to wifi access point, but the problem i am facing that is the wifi connection which i am creating is not getting remembered through out the reboots of the device.

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiConfiguration wc = new WifiConfiguration();
wc.SSID = "\"SSIDName\"";
wc.preSharedKey  = "\"password\"";
wc.hiddenSSID = true;
wc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;        
wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
wc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
int res = wifi.addNetwork(wc);
Log.d("WifiPreference", "add Network returned " + res );
boolean b = wifi.enableNetwork(res, true);        
Log.d("WifiPreference", "enableNetwork returned " + b );
```

What i want to archive is when i successfully connect to SSID i want to remember that network and on next reboot of the device Android should automatically connect to that SSID which was previously connected to.

Is that any API in `WifiManager` or `WifiConfiguration` to do so?

Thanks.

Comment: is it `WifiManager.saveConfiguration()` which saves the currently created wifi configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to save the created wifi configuration with call to `WifiManager.saveConfiguration()` which saves the currently created wifi configuration, also we need to set the highest priority to created wifi configuration so that on next reboot android wi-fi manager gives preference to this network.

Comment: `WifiManager.saveConfiguration()` is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Write a broadcast receiver for every Boot time set the username and password. Don't write any UI at that moment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for WPA :

```
        WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiConfiguration wc = new WifiConfiguration(); 
        wc.SSID = "\""+SSIDname+"\""; //IMP! This should be in Quotes!!
        wc.hiddenSSID = false;
        wc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.DISABLED;     
        wc.priority = 1;
        wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
        wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
        wc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
        wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
        wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
        wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
        wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
        wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
        wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
        wc.preSharedKey = "\"".concat(password).concat("\"");
        int res = wifi.addNetwork(wc);
```