# Switching Wifi Hotspots (Android)

Tags: java, android, wifi

I am trying to find a way to switch between WiFi hotspots, as the logic for hot spot switch on Android devices holds onto a hotspot even if the connection is so poor that it is useless.

I am trying to make my app better by being able to switch to another hotspot; but I have been unable to find anything on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go through [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-to-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-network-in-android-programmatically). It says how to connect to a network programmatically.

So, once device is connected to network, You could check if internet is available with this method:

```
public boolean isInternetAvailable()

    {
        try {
            InetAddress.getByName("google.com").isReachable(1000);     
            return true;
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

You might need a service to perform these actions in the background.

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't what I was after. I have a situation where the app is attached to a hot spot that has poor connection, even though I am right next to a different hot spot with a good connection. I would like to be able to switch to the new hot spot in code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756601/how-to-remember-wifi-configuration-and-connected-network-through-out-the-reboots

Comment: that would be helpful for you